# Calculate fixed Cost/day for multiple services on same date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Desired Output table `T` with Calculated Cost column:

```
SvcID   Code    ID   Date     Mins  Units   Cost
1       3000    15  4/4/2016    60   10     70
2       3000    17  4/4/2016    45   10      0
3       3000    15  5/2/2016    30   10     70
4       3000    18  5/2/2016    60   10      0
5       3000    10  5/2/2016    30   10      0
6       4200    16  2/1/2016    60   4      60
7       4200    9   2/1/2016    30   2      30
```

Query for calculating and displaying:

```
SELECT 
...
,CASE
  WHEN Code=4200 THEN Units*15
  WHEN Code=3000 THEN ?
 END AS Cost

 FROM ...
 WHERE Code IN ('3000','4200')
 GROUP BY ....;
```

Cost should be a total of 70 for all services offered on same date for Code 3000, irrespective of number of services offered. No relation between Minutes and Units for this Code for calculating Cost.

One way could be to calculate cost as 70 for any one service and make the remaining services cost 0 for same date. Can this be done in the `CASE` statement?

Any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Investigate Window functions [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Your case would become something like this:

```
-- New select statament
SELECT 
...
,CASE
  WHEN Code=4200 THEN Units*15
  WHEN Code=3000 THEN ( CASE WHEN DuplicateNum = 1 THEN 70 ELSE 0 END )?
 END AS Cost
FROM(
-- Your current query (with case statement removed) and ROW_NUMBER() function added
SELECT
..., ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Code, Date ORDER BY ID ) AS DuplicateNum
 FROM ...
 WHERE Code IN ('3000','4200')
 GROUP BY ....
) AS YourCurrentQuery;
```